# Add 3rd party library to Maven repository and use in project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

Trying to use 3rd party library in Java Eclipse Maven project.

Installing library to local jar repository:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile="C:\Projects\eclipse_ide_workspace\CAENRFIDLibrary.jar" -DgroupId=caen  -DartifactId=CAENRFIDLibrary -Dversion=1 -Dpackaging=jar
```

Got output that looks nice:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------< org.apache.maven:standalone-pom >-------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1
[INFO] --------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install-file (default-cli) @ standalone-pom ---
[INFO] Installing C:\Projects\eclipse_ide_workspace\CAENRFIDLibrary.jar to C:\Users\vico\.m2\repository\caen\CAENRFIDLibrary\1\CAENRFIDLibrary-1.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.472 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-11-17T11:45:41+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Trying to add it to my project pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>caen</groupId>
    <artifactId>CAENRFIDLibrary</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Eclipse pom.xml editor complains regarding library:

```
Missing artifact caen:CAENRFIDLibrary:jar:1.0
```

What I do wrong?

Comment: In your command you have use `-Dversion=1` where you are using `1.0` in your dependency...I would also recommend to use artifacts in lowercase only..like java package names...

Comment: Setting version helped. I'm ready to accept answer. Is it possible to attach library source code to library in order Eclipse could navigate in it?